# Pressing Enter on an ASP.Net Textbox to invoke button click event does not work in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, events, button, click, enter

I have looked all over for a solution, but have not been able to.

I have an WebForm page that contains textbox and a button (inside of a panel) that is used to filter a search. When pressing Enter after entering your criteria, it fires off the button click event.

This is a legacy application and this worked in all the browsers we've tested it on. Lately, it only works in IE 11. I made multiple attempts to get this to work in Chrome to no avail. The last implementation I used was based on this article [Capturing the Enter key to cause a button click](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17241/Capturing-the-Enter-key-to-cause-a-button-click).

Is it possible to capture a key-press event (Enter) to fire off a button click event in Chrome?

Thanks.
-Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey paul you can test the following, I've tried it and it worked with me, the panel one worked for me and it worked before in chrome:

put your wanted textbox that you wanted to work with the enter inside a panel and choose the default button for the panel to the id of the button you wanted like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="p1" runat="server" DefaultButton="b1">
         <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Worked like d champ. Thanks.